# Why it is passing index instead of FormControl object into FormControlNameDirective?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms

Refering to : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArrayName-directive.html :

HTML:

```
<form  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"> 
  <div formArrayName="cities">    
    <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; index as i">
        <input [formControlName]="i" placeholder="City">
   </div> 
 </div> 
 <button>Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Why it is passing *i* into formControlName instead of actual form control *city*.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is happening because you aren't getting the index correctly. You need to write it like this: `<div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; let i = index">`

Comment: Because this directive accepts name of control not value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this code is working with a form array named `cities`:

```
  <div formArrayName="cities">    
    <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; index as i">
        <input [formControlName]="i" placeholder="City">
   </div> 
 </div>
```

The names of the controls within the array are defined by their index numbers:
cities[0]; cities[1]; cities[2]; etc

The `city` variable is a reference to the control, not its "name", which for an array is the index.

Make sense?

Comment: Yes, each formControl needs an unique name to be referenced. index i is a perfect candidate for that.